# Variable instanciation VS double hash reference access

Tags: perl

Initially, I was looking for a fast way to access a hash ref element (with a default value if no value is available).

So I tried the following :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;
my $hashref = { };
for (0..249) {
  my $lIdx = $_ * 2;
  $hashref->{"MYKEY$lIdx"} = "MYVAL$lIdx";
}

sub WithVariable{
    my $result = $hashref->{"MYKEY$_[0]"};
    return defined $result ? $result : "NONE";
}

sub WithoutVariable{
    return defined $hashref->{"MYKEY$_[0]"} ? $hashref->{"MYKEY$_[0]"} : "NONE";
}
$|++;
my @preciousvalues1 = ();
my @preciousvalues2 = ();
my $dt = DateTime->now;
for (1..25000) { for (0..498) { push @preciousvalues1, WithVariable($_) } }
my $lag = DateTime->now - $dt;
print "With a variable: ", $lag->seconds, "\n";
$dt = DateTime->now;
for (1..25000) { for (0..498) { push @preciousvalues2, WithoutVariable($_) } }
$lag = DateTime->now - $dt;
print "Without a variable: ", $lag->seconds, "\n";

print "Done\n";
```

But the results seem to be quite random, and perl seems to do a lots of stuff after printing the "Done", and takes forever to exit.

My questions are :

1. What would be a neat implementation of a function allowing to access values stored in a hash with a default value if no value is found ?
2. What the hell is perl doing after it printed "Done" ? Garbage collection ?

Perl version : This is perl, v5.10.1 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread

Comment: You should really use the Benchmark module for these kinds of comparisons.  Benchmark is part of the core, so there is no reason not to use it.  http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Since version 5.10 you can use the `//` (defined-or) operator to test for defined-ness and assign a default value in one step.

```
$result = $hashref->{$key} // "NONE"
```

sets `$result` to `$hashref->{$key}` if that value is defined, and `"NONE"` otherwise.

2. More or less. If it bothers you, slap a

```
    use POSIX;
    POSIX::_exit(0);
```

at the end of your script. This will end your script immediately, bypassing Perl's normal shutdown routine (and any code you have put into `END { }` blocks). It's probably not a big deal to use it on this script, but it would normally not be a best practice to use `_exit`.

Answer (score 2):

As I already said in a comment, use [Benchmark](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html) to do these sorts of comparisons.  Benchmark handles all the fiddly details of timing the tests and printing a report.

Another thing worth mentioning is that your test is not testing what you think it is.  Your tests push values onto `@preciousvalues1` and `@preciousvalues2`.  Each test iteration adds approximately 500 results to one of the arrays.  Since you don't clear the arrays between iterations, you wind up with two arrays each with around **12.5 million** entries.  I guess that this is driving you to swap, and leading you to slow, semi-random execution times.  It is also the cause of the delay on exiting your program.  You've allocated a massive amount of RAM to those structures.  Perl wants to tear them down properly, and ensure that any destructors or END blocks are triggered.

Here's a cleaned up version of your test that focuses on hash access.  I've added mobrule's solution for comparison.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);


my $hashref = { };
for (0..249) {
  my $lIdx = $_ * 2;
  $hashref->{"MYKEY$lIdx"} = "MYVAL$lIdx";
}

sub WithVariable{
    my $result = $hashref->{"MYKEY$_[0]"};
    return defined $result ? $result : "NONE";
}

sub WithoutVariable{
    return defined $hashref->{"MYKEY$_[0]"} ? $hashref->{"MYKEY$_[0]"} : "NONE";
}

cmpthese( 25000, {
    "With Var" => sub {
        my @vals;
        push @vals, WithVariable($_) for 0..498;
    },
    "Without Var" => sub {
        my @vals;
        push @vals, WithoutVariable($_) for 0..498;
    },
    "Mobrule" => sub {
        my @vals;
        push @vals, $hashref->{"MYKEY$_"} // 'NONE' for 0..498;
    }
} );
```

With the following results on my system:

```
              Rate    With Var Without Var     Mobrule
With Var    1382/s          --         -0%        -49%
Without Var 1389/s          1%          --        -49%
Mobrule     2700/s         95%         94%          --
```

It's pretty clear that mobrule's solution is faster, and that there is only a tiny difference between the other two implementations.  The big difference is that mobrule's solution does not do a function call that the other two implementations use.

Comment: You need to change the Mobrule version to use `$hashref->{"MYKEY$_"}` to get an accurate benchmark. Although I expect it won't really change the results.

Comment: Thanks, Ven'Tatsu.  Yet another example of how easy it is to try to test one thing, and wind up testing another.  I fixed the code and updated the results.